# Yii2 Structure for Multitenancy System?

Tags: yii2, multi-tenant

I am using Yii2 advanced structure, but I need a "Second" backend that is going to  control the tenant users.

I just copy the backend folder and change the configuration for the cookies and the User Model. I don't know if this will be enough.

I just want some advice on how to do it, if someone already did it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar some time ago. Besides what you have done I have also changed the User component too to log in a different kind of user.

You should also add more folders in the tests so you can test that part too.

Anyway that should be enough yes.